# So many Major GCs when monitoring IntelliJ 2018.03?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

[Major GC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html#sthref64) is triggered by [`System.gc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--).

To avoid lots of Major GCs while starting *IntelliJ 2018.3*, I tried to configure the `idea64.vmoptions` with following VM options

<sub>*(directly copied from VisualVM JVM arguments)*</sub>

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2400m
-XX:NewSize=512M
-XX:MaxNewSize=512M
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xloggc:/home/hearen/.IntelliJIdea2018.3/gc_details.log
-XX:+CITime
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-XX:ErrorFile=/home/hearen/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/hearen/java_error_in_IDEA.hprof
-Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2018.3
-Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/hearen/.IntelliJIdea2018.3/config/idea64.vmoptions
-Didea.jre.check=true
```

I tried to avoid Minor and Major GCs as much as possible with **big enough** memory for *Young & Tenured Generation* ([-Xms512m -Xmx2400m -XX:MaxNewSize=512M -XX:NewSize=512M](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html)) and disabled the [`-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

But I still witnessed lots of Major GC in GC logs (in **VisualVM**, I saw 18 Major GC collections for Old Gen while 14 for Eden).

As I checked [`-XX:CMSTriggerRatio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABFAFAE) will be `80%` in default to start a CMS collection cycle, which seems not the cause but there are lots of CMS cycles in GC logs.

```
2019-03-18T18:53:40.683+0800: 176.928: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 54738K(150112K)] 476819K(621920K), 0.0516469 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
2019-03-18T18:53:40.734+0800: 176.979: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-03-18T18:53:40.797+0800: 177.043: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.063/0.063 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.07 secs] 
2019-03-18T18:53:40.797+0800: 177.043: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-03-18T18:53:40.800+0800: 177.045: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.003/0.003 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-18T18:53:40.800+0800: 177.045: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2019-03-18T18:53:45.872+0800: 182.117: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 3.168/5.072 secs] [Times: user=3.20 sys=0.00, real=5.07 secs] 
2019-03-18T18:53:45.872+0800: 182.117: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 423458 K (471808 K)]2019-03-18T18:53:45.872+0800: 182.117: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0511363 secs]2019-03-18T18:53:45.923+0800: 182.168: [weak refs processing, 0.0000925 secs]2019-03-18T18:53:45.923+0800: 182.168: [class unloading, 0.0183514 secs]2019-03-18T18:53:45.942+0800: 182.187: [scrub symbol table, 0.0381231 secs]2019-03-18T18:53:45.980+0800: 182.225: [scrub string table, 0.0013231 secs][1 CMS-remark: 54738K(150112K)] 478196K(621920K), 0.1099238 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs] 
2019-03-18T18:53:45.982+0800: 182.227: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2019-03-18T18:53:45.998+0800: 182.244: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-03-18T18:53:45.998+0800: 182.244: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2019-03-18T18:53:45.999+0800: 182.245: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-03-18T18:53:48.000+0800: 184.245: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 54738K(150112K)] 478965K(621920K), 0.0538103 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
```

**Perhaps Helpful**

<sub>To ensure the accuracy of the results, I tried several times for each configuration.</sub>

I tried to compare with & without `-XX:NewSize=512M -XX:MaxNewSize=512M`

1. WITH: Major -> 18 and Minor -> 14;
2. WITHOUT (Eden will be 266M): Major -> 10 and Minor -> 40;

---

#### My Questions

1. Why there are so many **Major GCs**?
2. Why so many *CMS*, what triggered them?
3. Cannot I reduce Minor and Major at the same time even when I got memory?

Any help will be strongly appreciated :)

Comment: not an answer, but when you play with GC options, one _might_ trigger another, so when you specify `MaxNewSize` and `NewSize` - you might be touching other parts of the GC algorithm, that in turn triggers some settings for when a Full GC happens. Did you try without them to see what happens? The very first thing that pops into my mind is that since these values are so big, the old space is pretty little.

Comment: I tried and then `Monor GC` increases which I was hoping to eliminate in the first place.

Comment: you *can't* do that - Minor GC is good, major is not that bad if it is not often.

Comment: I was trying to reduce GCs (which includes minor and major) and I see no reason why there are minor and major when memory is already enough. Here especially the major, why CMS so much?

Answer (score 1):

You are using CMS in your configuration. That means three types of pauses

1. **minor**/young collection [ParNew]
2. **concurrent** old space collections
3. **full** stop-the-world single threaded last resort collections

(see [Garbage collection in HotSpot JVM](https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html), article is old but explains GC logs snippets)

**minor** and **concurrent** are ok. **full** is bad.

VisualVM does not distinguish **concurrent** and **full**, thus number of "major" collection is very misleading for CMS GC.

PS
You may want to use "Visual GC" plugin to watch heap dynamics closely.
[image] [image]

Comment: All you mentioned, either I've been using already or I've known; could you please help to answer the questions listed above? Thank you for the help :)

Comment: My apologies, I've miss understood your question. Now I see you are concern about frequent CMS cycles. You probably need to post large log excerpt. One possible reason for such misbehavior on per 8 java was perm gen, I;m not sure if it works in similar way with metaspace - https://blog.ragozin.info/2012/06/story-of-relentless-cms.html

Comment: Thank you, Alexey, I will check it out and try to test more and post some logs here. Thank you, have a nice day!